Why is my user anonymous after logging in by OAuth2 with Spring Boot?
I am trying to connect OAuth authorization to my project via Github, but my user remains anonymous after success:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping
    public String home() {
        return "Hello, %s".formatted(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
    }
}

and output:
Hello, anonymousUser

Here is my SecurityFilterChain bean and application.yaml settings:
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, Converter<Jwt, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken> converter) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                                authorize
                                        .anyRequest()
                                        .permitAll()
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer ->
                        configurer
                                .jwt((jwt) -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(converter))
                )
                .sessionManagement(configurer ->
                        configurer
                                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .exceptionHandling(configurer ->
                        configurer
                                .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                                .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler())
                );
        return http.build();
    }

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            clientId: <hidden>
            clientSecret: <hidden>
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'

UPD:
I figured out that this is happening because of the settings:
.sessionManagement(configurer ->
    configurer
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
)

, but I don't understand how to turn it off? I want there to be no sessions in my application and communication to be exclusively through access tokens issued by Github, but instead I get the JSESSIONID set in a Cookie. How do I make sure that after successful authorization, access tokens are returned instead of setting Cookies?

Where and how do you expect the tokens to be stored between requests? You coded nothing to provide the frontend with the tokens your Spring OAuth2 client gets using authorization code flow.
You should probably read the OAuth2 essentials section of my tutorials.
oauth2Login (authorization code & refresh token flows in a Spring OAuth2 client) is something:

based on sessions
requiring protection against CSRF (because it relies on sessions)
implemented on OAuth2 clients (server-side), not on resource servers
used to get tokens from an authorization server and save them in session, not to build a security context from a Bearer token
handling tokens refreshing (if a refresh token is provided by the authorization server, and when access token expired or is about to)

Authorization server, client, and resource server are 3 different OAuth2 actors. Requests authorization based on a Bearer access token is a resource server business => oauth2Login has nothing to do on a resource server.
As a side note, if your frontend is a single-page or mobile application, you should not be trying to have it authorize its requests with Bearer tokens. Instead, you should be using sessions on an OAuth2 backend for frontend.

Why should I store a JWT token? The point of the token is not to store them. Is not it so? I contacted Github, redirected the user, he logged in and then I exchanged the authorization_code for a token. Can't I just give this token to the frontend and then it will communicate with the server simply by placing it in the Authorization header?

I probably misunderstood your question. I have a mobile application that interacts with the REST API. I want to store the token in the mobile application.

If you  are interested in why you should be using sessions between front & back ends, you may read this post from Spring Security team: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390

I exchanged the authorization_code for a token. You didn't do that. Your Spring OAuth2 client did, on the server. You coded nothing for the server to send the token to the mobile frontend nor for this frontend to store tokens, provide access token as Bearer authorization header for next requests to the backend, or update the access token when it expires using the refresh token, usually about every 5 minutes. And anyway, you should not be trying to send tokens to the frontend. Just learn to work with sessions between your front & back ends.

Fine. I realized that this standard assumes the use of sessions. There is still one question left: is it acceptable practice to get user information from a third-party service and issue your own JWT token based on it? To save the user from having to register and confirm the phone or email, but no more.

About any authorization server complying with OIDC does that (Keycloak, Auth0, Spring Authorization Server to name a few).

this standard assumes the use of sessions this is true only on authorization server and server-side clients, not on resource servers which can (and should) be stateless.
